# Android stop responding while scrolling list view

Tags: android, listview

I populated my list view with text and image using custom adapter.
There are about 82 items(both text and image) . All is working good but when I scroll my list to button my application stop responding. What should I do now.

Comment: you are probably loading the images on the ui thread. don't do that. there are plenty of libraries that will do that asynchronously for you. the most popular are univeral image loader, picasso, and glide.

Comment: Or better yet, use the new replacement of Listview which is the RecyclerView.  Although you still would REALLY need to offload your image loading via a separate UI thread...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, the main problem was entry in the array. The size of text array was greater than the size of image array. So while loading last text,it couldn't get any image for that size. Hence there was crashes of app.